# make UIView bigger than its parent view

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, frame, cgrect

I'm making an iPad app and I have a UIView structure as follows:

ViewA (parent) --> ViewB (subview to ViewA) --> ViewC (subview to ViewB)

ViewA is the same size as the screen.
ViewB is about half the size of the screen.
 
ViewC is half the size of ViewB.

Upon a certain event, I want to modify ViewC's frame so that ViewC covers the entire screen. What's the best way to do this? I'd rather not have ViewC's frame go outside of ViewB (and I can't change ViewB's frame).

Thanks!

Sunny

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, view B is no longer relevant if view C will occupy the whole screen. Is it possible/safe to remove the subview C from B in your design?

If so, then remove C from B, and then add it as a subview to A. You can even do it with an animation, using the static method `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` from [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

Comment: I do need to keep ViewB. I've made it more simple than it sounds. There's actually a number of intermediate views between my ViewA which covers the entire screen and my ViewB which is a subview several views below ViewA. So it would be a lot of work to remove all the intermediate views...

Comment: Then add an intermediary view called "ViewBC" which can hold either B or C in "fullscreen" as a subview, and keeping it placed correctly within "A". Also, notice that you can swap order of the subviews (`sendSubviewToBack:`, `bringSubviewToFront:`, ...). Or just bite the bullet and expand B outside of the bounds of C, make sure that `clipsToBounds` is NO (default).